# fetch co-owners comma separated in same column

Tags: mysql

Owners Table

| OwnerId | owners_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | deepak |
| 2 | raja |

Co-Owners Table

| id | OwnerId | Co-OwnerName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abc |
| 2 | 1 | xyz |
| 3 | 2 | def |
| 1 | 1 | efd |
| 1 | 2 | aye |

Output:

| Id | owners_Name | Co-owners_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | deepak | abc,xyz,efd |
| 2 | raja | def,aye |

Comment: And what is the question? PS. Show SQL queries which have you tried already.

Comment: @Akina Judging from the output, I suppose the OP would like to get the Co-OwnerNames (in a comma separated string) for each owner.

Comment: @blabla_bingo I see. But https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: show what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck.  also think about what determines the order of the comma separated values - why is it def,aye not aye,def?

Comment: SELECT A.Owners_Name , istagg(B.Co_ownersName, ', ') within group (order by B.Co_ownersName) Cownersname from Owners as A
JOIN co_owners as B
ON B.Owners_Id = A.OwnersId

Comment: you can edit your question and put that there.  are you asking about mysql?  that is not mysql syntax, and googling doesn't tell me what else it might be

Comment: ah, listagg, not istagg.  I think that's oracle.  are you using oracle?  please show output of `select version();` and `select * from V$VERSION;` (only one of those will work)

Comment: SELECT A.OwnersName , STRING_AGG(B.Name, ',') as coowners  from owners as A
JOIN coowners As B 
ON B.owners_Id= A.owners_Id

Comment: string_agg is a sql-server/t-sql function not available in mysql - if you are indeed seeking a mysql solution try group_concat and throw away the tutorial you are working from.

Comment: SELECT registerclient.Id , registerclient.RcName , GROUP_CONCAT(coowners.Name ORDER BY coowners.RCid) as coowners  from registerclient
left JOIN coowners 
ON coowners.RCid = registerclient.Id
GROUP BY registerclient.Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT registerclient.Id , registerclient.RcName , GROUP_CONCAT(coowners.Name ORDER BY coowners.RCid) as coowners  from registerclient
left JOIN coowners 
ON coowners.RCid = registerclient.Id
GROUP BY registerclient.Id
```